# Issue connecting Cypress to Postgres database

Tags: cypress

I'm running into an issue connecting to the database using cypress-postgres. The server has multiple databases along with multiple schemas. I tried multiple plugins, but can't find a solution that will allow me to specify a particular schema in a database. The server is reachable over the VPN.

I will need to do this with a SQL database.

For example: [image: Database Example.]

Error that is returned:

```
no relation for home
```

`package.json` has following dependencies:

```js
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Automated Tests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "cypress open"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": 
  },
  "author": "Michael Frazier 
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^5.8.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "cypress-commands": "^2.0.1",
    "cypress-downloadfile": "^1.2.1",
    "cypress-postgres": "^1.1.1",
    "cypress-postgresql": "^1.0.8",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-promise": "^10.5.8",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@4tw/cypress-drag-drop": "^2.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@cypress/skip-test": "^2.6.1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.9.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.21",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "cy-mobile-commands": "^0.3.0",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-fill-command": "^1.0.2",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-mailosaur": "^2.6.0",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "cypress-msteams-reporter": "^1.0.3",
    "cypress-plugin-tab": "^1.0.5",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1"
  }
}
```

`cypress.json` has DB credentials in following format:

```js
{
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true,
  "responseTimeout": 30000,
  "requestTimeout": 50000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 4000,
  "experimentalSourceRewriting": true,
  "experimentalStudio": true,
  "projectId": "aycmk8",
  "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/report",
    "charts": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "Melos Report"
  },

  "db":
  {"user": "postgres",
    "host": "",
    "database": "",
    "password": "",
    "schemas": "sct",
    "port": 5432
  }
}
```

Plugin in `cypress\plugins\index.js` file:

```js
module.exports = async (on, config) => {
  on('task',
    {dbQuery: (query)=> require('cypress-postgres')(query.query,query.connection)})
```

Spec file has following test:

```js
describe("Database Health Tests", function () {

  it('should ping the database to ensure its active ', function () {
    cy.task("dbQuery", {"query":"select * from home"})
  });
```

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72148473/3001761).

Comment: Thank - will not do again...